# Settings > Users > Unlock button does not work (20.04)

Tags: unlock

Settings > Users > Unlock button should trigger "Auth required" but does not work / is disabled in 20.04 Gnome, just prompts "Dialog is locked" on hover.
Duh!

`sudo gnome-control-center` I guess is not the point of a working GUI.

TIA